# How SQL Server handles concurrent requests?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Suppose a SQL Server table has two `MailID` columns, with max value = 5.

If two different users at the same time execute insert queries that try to insert `Max(MailId)+1` into the `MailID` column, is it possible that both new rows may get the value 6?

**I want to learn how SQL Server internally handles more than one request at the same time.**

Comment: Related question from same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708008/adding-maxvalue1-in-new-row-can-this-be-a-problem

Comment: Your question is very common. It would take at least fifty pages to just give you some introduction. If you want to try out and see for yourself, I have written a few examples when two connections simultaneously access one and the same row: [Developing Modifications that Survive Concurrency](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/developing-modifications-that-survive-concurrency/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible (as per JNK's answer: 2 *overlapping* MAX reads, both get 6, one fails with duplicate assuming a constraint)

Use IDENTITY columns for this very reason.

If you have some odd notion to not use IDENTITY, then you have to use lock granularity (TABLOCKX ) or semaphores (sp_getapplock) to *restrict* concurrency and allow only one process to run MAX at a time.

Edit:

Two requests that come in at the same time (or very close to it) run concurrently. They are both separate from each other but overlapping.

So each process will read the table using MAX and both get 6. At this point, both processes and reading and the INSERTs have not started yet.

The leading processes INSERTs 6, closely followed by the lagging process. The lagging process will get the unique key violation (you have uniqueness, right?)

If the gap between processes is enough so that the 2nd read happens *after* the 1st INSERT you're OK.

However, if you have enough calls that you have this risk of duplicate, then using locks/semaphores to decrease concurrency is madness...

Answer (score 5):

If there are no constraints in place to prevent duplicates, it will allow both.

Use an `Identity` field as I recommended in [your other question on a similar topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708008/adding-maxvalue1-in-new-row-can-this-be-a-problem)

If there are constraints, then one of them will be a millisecond before the other.  It's not realistic to think they would be **PRECISELY** the same time.  The first one will perform the insert, and the second will wait while the first has a lock in place.  Once the first releases the lock, the second will attempt it's insert and fail on a duplicate key insert.

Comment: JNK if there are no constaints will both insert in one time be executed together or one by one ? As SQL Server support multiple connectiosn in one time. How more then one requests are treated in one time ? Will be be executed together ?

Comment: @user576510: both INSERTs will be separate. Always. They are different connection/processes. Nothing combines these *at all*. If you have no constraint, your data will get corrupted...

Comment: @gbn, @JNK, I understand both will be seprate but my question is about their handling timing. Will both be executed together or one by one ?

Comment: @user576510: Neither. Discrete but *overlapping*

Comment: I disagree with the following: "If there are constraints, then one of them will be a millisecond before the other. It's not realistic to think they would be PRECISELY the same time". Collisions in RDBMS do happen, we do observe them, provided that we have enough activity.

Comment: @Alex - do they both apply a lock simultaneously?

Comment: @JNK there are many possible scenarios, and yes they may request a lock within a microsecond. Also be aware of conversion deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the internal Identity type for SQL server is the correct solution but the question was to "learn how SQL Server internally handles more than one request at the same time." Since I don't see that in any answers here I will explain. The Identity type both iterates AND stores a new value **atomically**. The old value is given as the identity for one requester only. An identity is not issued until the next value is persisted (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009063/are-disk-sector-writes-atomic). All requests for a new value of the identity column will happen serially and no duplicate key will occur unless you wrap your 64bit identity or duplicate a UUID which is virtually impossible. One thousand concurrent requests should give that many unique identities.

Atomic operations are a key feature of database servers if not their most important aspect.